# echo exec working but exec not

Tags: php, linux, shell, exec, shell-exec

I am using red hat enterprise edition n try making a simple php page..

When I try with  ...

```
 // html code
 <?php
 echo exec(<cmd>); 
 ?>
// rest html code
```

Its working fine

but when tried with ...

```
 // html code     
 <?php
 exec(<cmd>);
 ?>
 // rest html code
```

Its not working

even a simple command like cat,ls,etc not working and also I tried `2 > &1` then no error is printed .

What could be the possible error ???

Comment: What do you mean it "isn't working"? Do you mean that you get no output without an `echo`? You shouldn't, as `exec` won't write anything to stdout.

Comment: the command i am trying to use is actually sending a packet on other n/w

Comment: if I am using `-v` switch then also won't it write anything ?

Comment: Which switch are you talking about? `exec` is a function in PHP, it doesn't accept switches.

Comment: -v means `verbose` for command line and the command is used to sent a packet on network so I thought `exec` should work because I do not want its response on the same machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Docs:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

return a response from the command, you would need to print the response out as well

Example:

```
<?php
$response = array();
exec('whoami', $response);
print_r($response,true);
?>
```

Comment: accepted your answer because it suits more to the title and may guide someone in the right direction.Although I have added my answer too if someone would be interested what was the actual issue with me ..

Answer (score 0):

okkkkkkk ......... I solved the problem. Actually there were two issues ...

1. The `apache` user searches its command in `/usr/bin` folder by default and the command I was trying to use was located in `/usr/local/bin`. So I need to create a soft link of that command in the `/usr/bin` directory.
2. Secondly , `apache` is a less privilaged user than root so need to on the `sticky bit` of command so that apache could successfully run the command.

I hope this will help someone else also who will face the same problem in future.